# Eclipse in Linux - Error installing the Jcraft SFTP Plug-in

Tags: android, linux, eclipse

Me and my friend are working on a project using the Eclipse IDE,and we wanted to set up an SFTP facility on Eclipse to make our synchronization easier. My friend installed Eclipse via the official Debian (Kali Linux actually) repositories, while I installed it on my Ubuntu system by downloading the files and placing them in the correct places manually (all on the /opt folder). As a result, I also open Eclipse through the terminal.

Continuing the installation, we wanted to install the Android SDK, which worked fine for both of us. I downloades the files and installed them using the "Install Software" option in the Help tab, and my friend downloaded Android directly from the url.

Now, we have a problem with installing Jcraft sftp plug-in. My friend had no problem installing it directly from the url, while I tried both from the url and downloading the files manually, but in the first case I got the following error at the final phase of installing:

```
An error occurred while installing the items
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null -->     [R]com.jcraft.eclipse.team.sftp 0.0.2, action=).
Failed to prepare partial IU: [R]com.jcraft.eclipse.team.sftp 0.0.2.
```

while as regards the manual installation I can't get to find the right path for using the files to install the plug-in. Any advice on the above?

Answer (score -1):

From your post I don't know what versions of eclipse you and your friend are using, but I ran into the same problem with Luna.

While Eclipse Kepler seems fine, Luna requires a workaround: Install the "Eclipse 2.0 Style Plugin Support", which adds support for "running old Eclipse plugins that are not proper OSGi bundles."